# Icinga+Nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, monitoring

I installed Icinga 1.6.0beta and tried to install it's new web interface using this [manual](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/icinga-web-scratch.html). But it was written for Apache. So I used the following configuration file for nginx to run the interface, but no success. I get directory listing denied in error logs. Any help?

Note: /data/developers/icinga-web symlinked to /usr/local/icinga-web

```
server {
server_name developers.example.com;
access_log /var/log/nginx/dev.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/dev.error.log;
root /data/developers;

location / {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location /icinga-web/js/ext3/ {
    alias /usr/local/icinga-web/lib/ext3/;
}

location /icinga-web/ {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(/icinga-web)(/.*)$ /icinga-web/index.php?$2 last;
    }
}

try_files $uri $uri/ /icinga-web/index.php?$args;
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/icinga-web)(/.*)$;

    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I had to put the following line:

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .php5 .cgi
```

Into the php-fpm pool configuration file.

Of course, after I put that, I now get the following line error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /usr/local/icinga/sbin/tac.cgi on line 313
```

But hey, progress!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into almost the same problems years later, better late than never. (I marked the variables you have to set yourself with ***" % "***)

```
location @icinga {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_temp_path fastcgi;
        fastcgi_pass  %YOUR_SOCKET%;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /icingaweb2/index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME %ICINGA_WEB_LOCATION%/index.php;
        fastcgi_param ICINGAWEB_CONFIGDIR %ICINGA_CONFIG_DIR%;
}
location /icingaweb2 {
    alias %ICINGA_WEB_LOCATION%/public;
    try_files $uri @icinga;
}
```